# Python Selenium Message: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, mysql

Estoy desarrollando un web scraper en python que lo que hace es tomar usuarios y contraseñas de una base de datos y despues ir a una pagina web externa y llenar el formulario para despues iniciar sesion, funciona perfecto con el primer usuario y contraseña, pero cuando pasa al segundo me arroja que el boton "submit" no se puede localizar.

Alguna idea?

Les dejo el codigo que estoy usando:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", passwd="", db="seliso")

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM usuarios")

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    rfc = row[1]
    clave = row[2]

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://login.siat.sat.gob.mx/nidp/idff/sso?id=mat-ptsc-totp&sid=10&option=credential&sid=10")

    username = driver.find_element_by_name("Ecom_User_ID")
    password = driver.find_element_by_name("Ecom_Password")

    username.send_keys(rfc)
    password.send_keys(clave)

    submit = driver.find_element_by_name("submit")

    submit.click()

    driver.get("https://www.siat.sat.gob.mx/PTSC/")

    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Buzón tributario")
    link.click()

    driver.get("https://www.siat.sat.gob.mx/PTSC/cerrarSesion")

    driver.close()

db.close()
```

Comment: Sin saber mucho más, igual tienes que desloguear al primer usuario para que puedas loguear a un segundo y aparezca un botón de login/submit,...

Answer (score 1):

Me he encontrado muchas veces con el problema que describes. El motivo para que no vea el elemento en caso de que no sea que estés identificándolo mal, es que no le has dado tiempo a que cargue todo el sitio y se construya el html a partir del código que lo define.
  Hay muchas soluciones eficientes, incluyendo clases de la propia librería de `selenium` pero en mi caso particular suelo resolver el tema esperando uno o dos segundos después de que se realice la carga de la página

```
import time

# Todo tu código...
driver.get('...')

# Haces tiempo para que se forme el contenido del html y sea "visible"
time.sleep(2)

# Continúas con tu código
username = driver.find_element...
```

Espero haber ayudado. Un saludo!